# How do I remove duplicate values or words from multiple files in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have multiple files in a directory and they have duplicate records. There can be more than one duplicate for the same value.

sample.txt

```
#My first file created on Tuesday
[active]
row = org\xcfte, org\hrxen
speed = org\hrxen, org\kiopm7, org\0987hy
col = org\lop09k, org\0987hy
```

sample_2.txt

```
#My second file created on Wednesday
[active]
row = org\xcfte, org\0okilh
speed = org\hrxen, org\0okilh
col =  org\0987hy
```

and so on for multiple files

Expected output

```
sample:
org\xcfte
org\hrxen
org\kiopm7
org\0987hy
org\lop09k

sample_2:
org\xcfte
org\0okilh
org\hrxen
org\0987hy
```

from first file - org\hrxen and org\0987hy should appear only once and from the 2nd file 'org\0okilh' should appear once.

I tried

```
lines = File.read('/path/to/file')
lines.split("\n").uniq.join("\n")
```

as well as

```
File.readlines("*.txt").uniq
```

but duplicate entries are not removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've tried the last one `File.readlines("file.txt").uniq` and it's working great with this kind of file:

file.txt

```
org\xcfte
org\hrxen
org\hrxen
org\kiopm7
org\0987hy
org\0987hy
org\lop09k
```

The work here is to parse your file correctly because doing `File.readlines("file.txt").uniq` on this kind of file...

```
[active]
row = org\xcfte, org\0okilh
speed = org\hrxen, org\0okilh
col =  org\0987hy
```

...will never print your expected output

**Edit** Here is a solution working for me

```
array = []

file = File.read('file')
file.split(' ').each do |line|
    # I push the line if it is not already inside the array and if it contains the substring "org"
    formated = line.gsub(',', '')
    array.push(formated) unless array.include? formated or !line.include? "org"
end
puts array
```

Output for sample 1:

```
org\xcfte
org\hrxen
org\kiopm7
org\0987hy
org\lop09k
```

Comment: Problem is all my files are of that format only. That's where I'm stuck and I'm not sure how to get rid of the duplicate strings.

Comment: Simple and Elegant, thanks a lot !! Could yo kindly explain the `array.push(line.gsub(',', '')) unless array.include? line.gsub(',', '') or !line.include? "org"` as that would be helpful for a beginner like me. Thanks again

Comment: Well, after I split the file, I got multiple lines like "org\lop09k," for exemple. So this part means that I want to push this line into the array only if it contains "org" and if it is not already inside this array. I do this removing the comma of course with the gsub function.

Comment: +1 for the clear explanation. just wondering why `!` before `!line.include? "org"` Does it have a specific purpose and why not `line.include? "org"`

Comment: Yeah because I use `unless` not `if` , so I have to use the opposite expression `!line.include? "org"`.

Literally it means: push into array unless the line is already in the array or doesn't `(!)` contains substring "org"

Comment: Great thanks a lot for your explanation

Out of context question, do you take any online training for RUby  or hold any blog of yours so that I can subscribe and pay if needed. 

Im very new to Ruby and Programming and really interested to learn Ruby

Comment: I followed a little bit the Ruby formations of Grafikart [link](https://www.grafikart.fr/formations/ruby). He is a French developer just like me who explains the basics of Ruby and Rails. For me the best way to learn is to find a project and jump in ! (learn on the job). You'll face a shit tons of problems and you'll find the solutions step by step and this is how you learn a language for me. For example, I started a project with Rails without totally mastering Ruby so I had to deal with a lot of problems and that has only strengthened my knowledge, actually I'm surfing with Rails :D

Comment: Really appreciate your help here, the link shared in in French . Does it have an English version? Many thanks again..

Comment: I don't think there is an english version of his formation :/ No problem have fun with Ruby !